# Office crashes when saving a file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, office

Since about 2 weeks our users complain that office files (Excel or Word) which are stored in SharePoint sites are closing without a message and opens a new blanko file. It looks like that the process crashes cause the file on SharePoint was not updated. We've also checked the temporary internet files content.mso folder and the file is still in there (with all changes).
Has anybody an idea what can cause such a behaviour?
Thanks Michael

Comment: We had a similar problem with a few documents. It seemed to be triggered by leaving comments through the web app. We could not reproduce the problem repeatably. For the documents in question, it appeared the SharePoint metadata was corrupted. Downloading, deleting from SP, and uploading fixed the problem every time.

Answer (score 0):

We had that experience with Document Information Panel turned on.  I did not find a solution.  But we noticed that it worked when accessing SP10 with Office 13 products.